# Cannot import google fonts with Stylus on Vue

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, stylus

I created a project using Vue 2 with the webpack template. In the meantime I'm also working on a "component library" that I'm using locally in the project above (using `npm link`).

I'm using Stylus in both projects.

Now in `App.vue`, to be able to customize the appearance of the library, I'm importing the separate stylus files from the linked package like this:

```
<template>
    <...>
</template>

<script>
...
</script>

<style lang="stylus">
@import "~snue/src/stylus/vars"
/* 
    Override default variables
 */
fontSans    = "Ubuntu"
fontMono    = "Ubuntu Mono"
fontNumber  = "Dosis"

lighter     = lighten(light, 5)
lightish    = darken(light, 5)
darker      = darken(dark, 5)
darkish     = lighten(dark, 5)
primary     = crimson
secondary   = darkcyan

// Import components and style
@import "~snue/src/stylus/components"
@import "~snue/src/stylus/styles"

// Custom styles
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700");
.f-number
    font-family: fontNumber, Courier New, Courier, monospace

body
html
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

html
    background-color: darkish

body
    background-color: dark
    color: light
</style>
```

Everything works fine, except for the fact that `@import url(...)` rules with google fonts don't seem to work.

When I run `npm run dev` the browser uses the fallback fonts I specified and I cannot see any request made in the network panel of the chrome inspector.

When I build the library with webpack and the extract plugin instead, I can clearly see the `@import url()` rules in the generated css file.

Has this something to do with some Vue setting?

Comment: Try using `@require` instead of `@import`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter `@require` won't work with `url(...)`, it throws an error 'You cannot @require a url'

Comment: Since you're doing this in your SFC, you may need an appropriate loader to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was `postcss-import` complaining about `@import` rules:

```
@import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)
```

I reverted back to version `7.*` and now it's working fine. If you cannot switch to an older version below is a workaround that initially worked for me.

### Workaround for postccs-import > 11.*

It's not a real solution, but I found a way to avoid this problem: I wrapped `@import` inside a `@css` rule, and now it works:

```
// Custom styles
@css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700");
```

To my surprise, I can even use stylus variables inside the `@css` literal block:

```
// Custom styles
fontNumberSource = replace(" ", "\+", fontNumber)
@css
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family="+fontNumberSource+":400,700");
```

So I'm ok with this for now